# Problems with strtok in c linux

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE * f_enter;
void CleanLineFeed(char * pCad)
{
    char *cTmp;
    char *ptr;

    cTmp=pCad;
    ptr = strtok(cTmp, "\r\n\r");
    strcpy(pCad, ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char datenter[127];
  int i;
  f_enter=fopen("data.txt","r");
  if(f_enter == NULL)
  {
     printf("No data.txt.\n");
     return 1; 
  }
  while ( fgets(datenter, 127, f_enter) )
  {
        CleanLineFeed(datenter);
        for(i=0; i < strlen(datenter);i++)
        {
           printf("%c-%0X\n",datenter[i], datenter[i]);

        }
        printf("----------------------\n");
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

when i run it on Windows there is no error but
when i run it on Linux give me a segmentation fault error

Please, i strongly appreciate some kind of help

Comment: Note that the repeat of `\r` in `"\r\n\r"` is not necessary.  You should probably check the return from `strtok()` before using it; it can be a NULL pointer.  You should also, definitely, include `<string.h>`.  Also, if you're on Linux, you should be compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or thereabouts, and refining your code until it compiles cleanly (or using `clang` with the options instead of GCC).

Comment: Also note that you should not use `strlen()` in a loop condition unless the length of the string varies during the course of the loop, which it doesn't in this code.

Comment: Suggest replacing `CleanLineFeed(datenter);` with  `datenter[strcspn(datenter, "\r\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all warnings.  (the posted code outputs LOTS of warnings.) fix the warnings.  (in gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you forgot to

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer; that solves the problem

Answer (score 5):

Man page on Ubuntu 14.04 for strcpy says "The strings may not overlap".
"CleanLineFeed" performs an overlapped strcpy().

( [This Link describes the issue](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Copying-and-Concatenation.html) )

Windows implementation of "strcpy" may differ from Linux's implementation,
which may explain why one crashes and the other doesn't.